# Center Unordered list horizontally

Tags: html, css, list, alignment, unordered

I'm having trouble *centering* a horizontal un-ordered list that I have on a very basic 'coming soon' page.

You can follow the [link to the site](http://deangrobler.com/) and have a look at the code and so on. You'll notice that the horizontal list with the 3 social icons are not quite centered relative to the big header and the email address, seems to be floating to the right a little bit.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: @Mr.Alien - It's really hard to tell, it kinda messes with your eyes doesn't it? If that is the case. How do I align my email address properly? All text in the body element is supposed to be centered.

Comment: I just saw it with a scale, lol your ul is towards right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `padding-left:0;` on your `ul` element.

This will override the default browser `-webkit-padding-start: 40px;` which Google Chrome is offsetting the center position. Other browser defaults may vary.

Tested in Google Chrome and this resolves the issue.

Comment: A very quick fix, thank you. Actually feel embarrassed having to ask a question with such a basic fix haha. Why was there left padding applied to it in the first place?

Comment: Perhaps it's because by default some padding is applied to the li items to 'indent' it a litte bit?

Comment: @DeanGrobler If you use Google Chrome Inspector, or FireBug etc, you can see `-webkit-padding-start: 40px;` being applied on `ul` elements by the browser. Setting `padding-left:0;` will override this.

Comment: @DeanGrobler Each browser has is own set of default styles it applies to the document, most browsers will add `padding-left` to list elements.

Comment: Referencing a reset.css would've probably avoided this little problem. And future ones.

Comment: @DeanGrobler True, however there is a debate about whether reset.css should be used. Browsers put defaults for a reason. http://sixrevisions.com/css/should-you-reset-your-css/

Answer (score 1):

Remove the left padding from the `.social_list` element.

```
.social_list {
  padding: 0;
}
```

Firebug makes figuring this kind of problem out much easier as it will show you the padding and margins on elements when you inspect the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

@Curt answer is right but you need to reset your elements, and you are actually facing this issue because of it

Use this to reset browser default, I always use this instead of `CSS Reset` stylesheet..

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Than you don't need to declare `padding-left: 0;` for every `ul` you use on your web page, because browsers set default styles for some elements and hence you are facing this problem